# How to use TypeScript code sharing (paths) in the root directory for config files?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, config

I have a project structure that goes like this:

- common-project

  - app

    - utilities

      - src

        - folders containing shared code
- project-two

  - src

    - folders containing specific code
  - tsconfig.json
  - jest.config.ts
- project-three

  - src

    - folders containing specific code
  - tsconfig.json
  - jest.config.ts

And I want to be able to extract common code/configurations from the config files (such as jest.config.ts) to my common app, so there is only one place to update them in future. However, using the paths I have set up in my tsconfig (@core) it fails to recognise this "module" anywhere outside of the /src/ folder (in project-two & project-three) when running jest/the project. However if I update this to the relative path (../common-project/etc) then jest/the project runs perfectly fine - with the correct configuration?

and in my tsconfig.json I have:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "target": "es2019",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
        "paths": {
            "@core/*": ["../common-project/app/utilities/src/*"]
        },
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "typeRoots": ["cdk/node_modules/@types", "./node_modules/@types"],
        "types": ["node", "jest"]
    },
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../common-project"
        },
        {
            "path": "../common-project/app/utilities"
        }
    ],
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "./cdk/**/*.ts",
        "./jest.config.ts",
        "./tsconfig.json"
    ],
    "exclude": ["./cdk/cdk.out"]
}
```

and in my jest.config.ts:

```
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from "ts-jest";
// import { initialise } from "../common-project/app/utilities/src/shared/config/jest.config";
import { initialise } from "@core/shared/config/jest.config";
import { compilerOptions } from "./tsconfig.json";

export default initialise(
    pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {
        prefix: "<rootDir>/",
    }),
    {}
);
```

// import { initialise } from "../common-project/app/utilities/src/shared/config/jest.config";

^this is the import which works when swapped out

and initialise (the common setup function I'm trying to use for Jest; however this premise will be extended to other configs such as eslint) is in the shared folder of common-project, like:

```
export function initialise(pathsToModuleNameMapper: any, overrides = {}): any {
    console.log("INITIALISE!!!");

    return {
        bail: 1,
        coverageDirectory: "coverage",
        moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "node"],
        preset: "ts-jest",
        roots: ["src"],
        testEnvironment: "node",
        testMatch: [
            "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
            "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)",
        ],
        transform: {
            "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
        },
        collectCoverage: true,
        verbose: true,
        moduleDirectories: ["node_modules"],
        moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper,
        ...overrides,
    };
}
```

So how can I get this to work while using the defined path, @core, instead of a relative path like "../.." in my root directory?

I've done things like this before using gitHub tagging/NPM for adding it as a dependency, but for this project it is a requirement to use the code sharing ability of TS.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias this can be solution

Comment: Thanks - it does do what I needed. Annoying the path sharing doesn't work though...

Comment: @Theo are you using multiple projects in different repos or a monorepo?

Comment: @vamsiampolu the project using multiple projects in different repo's at the moment. I advocate for monorepo's but we aren't there yet